# Trying to change database tables storage engine to innodb gives error "invalid default value for 'post_date'"

Tags: database, date-time, innodb

I have a live WordPress website. Most of the tables are using `MyISAM` storage engine with `UTF-8` encoding. I need to switch their storage engine to `innodb`. But when I try to change the engine, I get errors like `invalid default value for 'post_date'` & `invalid default value for 'user_registered'`.

I can see other related(but not similar) issues says that I should

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

While others say I should

```
SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

How can I skip the issue that `datetime` columns are showing `invalid default value for 'COL_NAME'` issue?
Is it safe if I changed the `datetime` format and allowed invalid dates? Will that make errors in WordPress?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?